# How to publish an asset to the AssetStore as a custom package?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, store

I am working on a tool that I want to now publish to the AssetStore. However, I ran into an issue. I want my tool to be imported into a 'Packages' folder. I have a root folder where in that folder there is a package.json file and another folder where inside there are all the tool files. These files are some images and precompiled dll files.
I also have a special folder 'Editor Default Resources' folder inside the Assets folder, where inside I have a subfolder where I store some easy-to-access editor resources.

So my question would be how do I ensure that the root folder would be imported to a 'Packages' folder when imported from the AssetStore? Because in order to upload it to the AssetStore I need this root folder to be within the Assets folder.

I am a bit confused as to how this all works and would really appreciate the help.

Thank you

Comment: **Why** do you specifically require it being installed as a Package into the `Packages` folder?

Comment: Primarily for organizational purposes, I'd say. It is much neater to have it stored in a separate folder as a package, rather than cluttering the project directory.
Although, I think I know more or less how to do this. There is an experimental way of uploading a package, by using UNITY_ASTOOLS_EXPERIMENTAL define. However, when it comes to the default editor resources folder, I'll have to figure something out for that.

Comment: afaik all the things hosted on the AssetStore are always installed into the `Assets` folder ... so I would rather claim if yours is the exception it is rather "unexpected" and experimental (e.g. for everything in the Assets you can simply modify or remove it from a project, for anything in the Packages it is read-only and needs to go through the PackageManager .. you would be kinda confuse people I guess) ... Alternatively you could still have your assets imported into `Assets/Packages/YourPackageName`

Answer (score 1):

## It's possible!

And, by the way, Unity's `Asset Store Tools` is installed in `Packages/com.unity.asset-store-tools` folder, not in `Assets` folder.

You can use "hybrid package".
https://github.com/needle-tools/hybrid-packages.

I didn't test if it works properly uploaded to Asset Store (my asset is not ready yet), but it definitely works with .unitypackage (so should work with Asset Store).

## How to install and use:

### Install `upm-in-unitypackage`

There are two options to install the package:

1. Install package by name `com.needle.upm-in-unitypackage`.
2. Or use custom registry to install it directly from Package Manager ui.

```
Name: OpenUPM
URL:  https://package.openupm.com/
Scope(s): com.needle
```

For me, only option 2 (custom registry) have worked.

### Export or upload your package

Now you can:

- either select your package folder (inside Packages) and use `Assets/Export Package...` menu to pack it into `.unitypackage`.
- or upload it directly using `Asset Store Tools/Asset Store Uploader` menu. You will see new `Local UPM Package` option in the dropdown.

### Summary

Both `.unitypackage` packed with this tool or directly published asset in this way will be imported or installed in Packages/your-package folder.

There is quite good readme on this tool, read it if I was not clear enough :) https://github.com/needle-tools/hybrid-packages.

Answer (score 0):

Posted a quick guide, how upload upm package to Asset Store

using define #UNITY_ASTOOLS_EXPERIMENTAL

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-W7BtzhHUpA